# Can you play with both local and online players at the same time?

Tags: ps4, helldivers

I am considering to buy [Helldivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helldivers), but would like to know if it's possible to play with two local and two online players at the same time, so that if I have a friend over we can play with other remote friends.

So: **Can you mix couch co-op with online co-op in Helldivers on PS4?**

I could not find any information on that, and the neither the co-optimus [info page](http://www.co-optimus.com/game/3097/playstation-3/helldivers.html) nor [coop FAQ](http://www.co-optimus.com/article/12920/helldiversco-op-faq.html#question2) for Helldivers seem to have that information.

Actually the info page says:

> Local + Online Play
> Up to 4 Local or Online

I am just not sure if that's an exclusive "or" or means that you combine the two local and online players.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [IGN](http://www.ign.com/articles/2015/03/14/helldivers-review) you can mix those two:

> Helldivers’ drop-in co-op makes forming a party easy from the couch, online, **or a mix of both**

Comment: Cool, just what I was hoping for.